# How to upload a files in WordPress custom page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom page template. This template have a custom form that user can upload a file. Now, the uploaded file/s will not upload in the MySQL but in the file system/local folder (local computer).

I already have a PHP snippet, but the code is not working I'm getting an errors.

How to fix this?

Snippet:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $lastName = isset($_POST['lastName']) ? $_POST['lastName'] : '';
    $resumeFile = isset($_FILE['resumeFile']['name']) ? $_FILE['resumeFile']['name']: '';

$info = pathinfo($_FILES['resumeFile']['name']);
$ext = $info['extension'];
$file_rename= $lastName.$ext; 

$target = 'C://xampp/htdocs/files/'.$file_rename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resumeFile']['tmp_name'], $target);
}
```

Errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: resumeFile .... on line 130
Notice: Undefined index: extension .... on line 131
Notice: Undefined index: resumeFile .... on line 135
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following snippet, to upload files on different directory other than default `uploads` directory.

```
function change_my_upload_directory( $dir ) {
    return array (
        'path'   => WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/your-custom-dir',
        'url'    => $dir['baseurl'] . '/wp-content/your-custom-dir',
        'subdir' => '/your-custom-dir',
    ) + $dir;   
}

if( isset( $_FILES[ "resumeFile" ] ) ) {

    if ( !function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }
    // Overrides the uploads directory location
    add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'change_my_upload_directory' );       

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES[ "resumeFile" ], array( 'test_form' => false ) ); 

    // Remove the filter, so that subsequant uploads will be dsent to default uploads directory
    remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'change_my_upload_directory' );

    return $movefile;

}    
return false;
```

`wp_handle_upload` will return an object which contains the following properties

```
$movefile[ 'file' ] // uploaded file object
$movefile[ 'url' ] // current url ( file location ) of the file
$movefile[ 'type' ] // uploaded file type
```

If `wp_handle_upload` fails it will return error object, you can check for failed upload like this

```
if( isset( $movefile[ 'error' ] ) ) {
    // handle the error
}
```

Comment: what is the file will save to? I need is to save the files in file system/local computer

Comment: The file will be uploaded into `/wp-content/uploads/` directory, yes which will be your local PC ( if the wordpress is on your local machine ) or your server ( your hosted machine on the cloud )

Comment: No, just leave as it is.

Comment: the file is not saving

Comment: Does your `uploads ` directory has a proper permissions.? you can check the folder permission by just go to `wp-admin/media/Add New` and try to upload a file.

Comment: Can you look into your `error.log` file and find any exception thrown related to the file upload.? probably at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: it's working now. question, can i save the file in the designated folder? not the default folder for all uploaded files

Comment: It's possible, but it is advisable store your files inside the `wp-content` directory.

Comment: I use your updated answer, but I noticed `$attachment_id` is missing. How to add the `$attachment_id` in the updated code? I need that id to call the file name and retrieve it with download link.